# Reading a XML file dataStoreBD = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params) returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, datastore, geotools

I am having some problems developing a `Maven project` with `Eclipse`. I tried to search on the net, but there is nothing similar.

To sum up, I am using the WFSDataStore (geotools) to get the collection of features from an [XML](http://pastebin.com/fQW4ApaE) and then adding to a Database.

There are two different behaviours:

1. When I do `Run As > Java Application` everything is correct and the code is working.
2. When I do `Run As > Maven` (`clean install tomcat:run-war`). There is an error on line **dataStoreBD = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);**, where dataStore is null:
   (If you want to check the [getCapabilities](http://pastebin.com/8BChzmJY) parameter)

   ```
   public static void dataAccess(String getCapabilities, WFSDataStoreFactory dsf) throws Exception {
   // Variables
   // WFS Connection
   Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
   connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, getCapabilities);
   connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.PROTOCOL.key, false);
   connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.LENIENT.key, true);
   connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.MAXFEATURES.key, "5");
   connectionParameters.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.TIMEOUT.key, 600000);

   // Database Connection
   DataStore dataStoreBD = null;
   Transaction transaction = null;
   Filter filter = null;

   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put("dbtype", configTypeDatabase);
   params.put("host", configIp);
   params.put("port", configPort);
   params.put("schema", configUser);
   params.put("database", configDatabase);
   params.put("user", configUser);
   params.put("passwd", configPassword);
   params.put("accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed", true);
   dataStoreBD = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
   // Etc. }
   ```

   The parameters are correct. I am getting them from a configuration file stored in my computer and I debugged like a thousand times to know what is really happening, but maybe there is a problem that I cannot see.
   After this code I have another piece:

   ```
   SimpleFeatureSource initialBDFeatureSource = dataStoreBD.getFeatureSource(configDatesTable);
   FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> ifs = initialBDFeatureSource.getFeatures().features();
   ```

   The first line ends the program with this error:

   > java.lang.NullPointerException
   >   at com.sitep.imi.acefat.server.daemon.InsertarBBDDDaemon.dataAccess(InsertarBBD
   >   DDaemon.java:972)

Comment: I assume this is part of a web service? How are you building the war file? You may be breaking the spi files.

Comment: @iant Sorry, but what are the spi files? Well, I have configured the pom.xml to build a .war file. Tell me specifically what you want to know and I will tell you about it.

Comment: See http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/welcome/use.html (search FactoryFinder) if you don't take care you can lose the .spi files that tell GeoTools where to find it's factories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I deployed the project to try something else (using `tomcat7` and adding the information of `tomcat.xml` (project path from `Eclipse's workspace`) to context.xml (`tomcat7` path: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf`).

Then I was studying the connections (`pool`, `jndi` and `jdbc`) because I was not able to connect properly to my database. That is why I endeded up changing the `jdbc` (a general-purpose interface to relational databases) connection to `jndi` (a general-purpose interface to naming systems) connection, like the following:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("dbtype", configTypeDatabase);
params.put("jndiReferenceName", "java:comp/env/jdbc/DBName");
params.put("accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed", true);
params.put("schema", configUser);
```

I omit some parameters because they are not significant nor irrelevant for `jndi` connection. The reason why is a little bit tricky because after resolving it I can't even explain it. For ever reason when I tried to run the `Java Application` or `option 1` locally it always worked, but I defined the connection as a lookup (`<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/DBName"/>`) so it only works with `jndi` when you have to run or deploy it with `maven`.

If I find more information I will update my answer to clear my it or improve it.